# Removing null values in a data frame

Tags: r, null

I'm really new to R so it would be great if there is an solution I can easily understand.
I have a data set which contains two columns, a date and a price, and the price can be null in some cases.
I tried to remove these values with `na.omit`, `complete.cases`, but it seems they are just for NA-values.

The rows look like this

```
2017-05-31 12615.059570
2017-06-01 12664.919922
2017-06-02 12822.940430
2017-06-05         null
```

So is there a way to remove null-values in a data frame?

Comment: First set all `NULL`-values to `NA`'s, and then use `complete.cases()`.

Comment: Deal with a problem before it becomes a *real* problem: `myData <- read.table("myFile.txt",  na.strings = c("null", "NA"))`. Related, possible duplicate post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13822801/680068

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also remove the row by finding the row that includes "null" and then redefining your `data.frame()` without the row:

**Code:**

```
df <- df[!df$V2 == "null", ] 
# "!" negates, so this statement represents: keep all rows in which V2 is not equal to "null"
          V1           V2
1 2017-05-31 12615.059570
2 2017-06-01 12664.919922
3 2017-06-02 12822.940430
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"2017-05-31 12615.059570
 2017-06-01 12664.919922
 2017-06-02 12822.940430
 2017-06-05     null", header = F, sep = "", stringsAsFactors = F)

          V1           V2
1 2017-05-31 12615.059570
2 2017-06-01 12664.919922
3 2017-06-02 12822.940430
4 2017-06-05         null
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you provided no sample data using `dput()`, I do not know the format of your NULL-values (is ir a 'real' NULL, of text?)...

The code below should work when your NULL is a character-value.

```
library(data.table)
data <- fread("
2017-05-31 12615.059570
2017-06-01 12664.919922
2017-06-02 12822.940430
2017-06-05         NULL")

data[ data == "NULL"] <- NA
data[ complete.cases(data),]

#            V1           V2
# 1: 2017-05-31 12615.059570
# 2: 2017-06-01 12664.919922
# 3: 2017-06-02 12822.940430
```